# How to set actionbar title in the Fragment programmatically if I need to go to roomDatabase and jetPackDatastore for the values for it?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-room, android-jetpack

I try to set title on the toolbar by choosing category of  that the fragment shows, for this I need to go to the jetPack dataStore to take the catigoryNumber: Int and use this int to fetch the respective categoryName from roomDatabase; I wrote the code (look the code on the Fragment below) and the title has become "StandaloneCoroutine{..." (and I don't see what is written next 'cause of not enough place in the toolbar).

How to set the title I need? Appreciate any help

In Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class VocabularyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.recycler_layout),
    VocabularyAdapter.OnVocItemClickListener {

    private val viewModel: VocabularyViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var searchView: SearchView

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val binding = RecyclerLayoutBinding.bind(view)
        val vocabularyAdapter = VocabularyAdapter(this)
        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.apply {
                adapter = vocabularyAdapter
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                itemAnimator = null // ХЗ НАДО ЛИ
            }
        }

        viewModel.words.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            vocabularyAdapter.submitList(it)
        }

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        viewModel.categoryNumber.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { 
            (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = viewModel.getCategoryName(it).toString()
        } // I believe that this method is incorrect
    }
```

In ViewModel:

```
class VocabularyViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val wordDao: WordDao,
    private val preferencesManager: PreferencesManager,
) : ViewModel() {

    val preferencesFlow = preferencesManager.preferencesFlow
    // other methods

    val categoryNumber = preferencesFlow.asLiveData()

    fun onChooseCategoryClick(chosenCategory: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        preferencesManager.updateCategoryChosen(chosenCategory)
    }

    fun getCategoryName(categoryNumber: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        wordDao.getCategoryName(categoryNumber)
    }
```

In Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT categoryName FROM category_table WHERE categoryNumber = :categoryNumber")
fun getCategoryName(categoryNumber: Int): Flow<String>
```

In PreferencesManager:

```
val preferencesFlow = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading preferences", exception)
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            val categoryChosen = preferences[PreferencesKeys.CATEGORY_CHOSEN] ?: 0
            categoryChosen
        }
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

In XML NavGraph file:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/vocabularyFragment"
    android:name="space.rodionov.swedishdriller.VocabularyFragment"
    android:label="Vocabulary"
    tools:layout="@layout/recycler_layout" >
    <argument
        android:name="categoryChosen"
        app:argType="integer"
        android:defaultValue="0" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: Can you please check 2 things. 1) Check if you're able to set the static title e.g `(activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "From frg"` 2) Can you please debug and check what `viewModel.getCategoryName(it).toString()` is returning?

Comment: 1) Yes I wrote "my own title" and the toolbar show it on opening the Fragment; 2) that method returns (I dont know why) this exact string: "StandaloneCoroutine{Completed}@799defa" . I added the part of NavGraph XML file which is for that particular Fragment, added to the bottom of the question; maybe I chould pay attention to the "label" line there, I don't know..

Comment: Yupp. That's the problem you're directly converting co-routine to String you're not consuming it's result.

Answer (score 0):

In your `VocabularyViewModel` you're setting `getCategoryName` directly to co-routine by using `=`

```
fun getCategoryName(categoryNumber: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        wordDao.getCategoryName(categoryNumber)
    }
```

If you're looking to fetch Name synchronously here then you should have

```
fun getCategoryName(categoryNumber: Int) = wordDao.getCategoryName(categoryNumber)
```

And in your query DAO

```
@Query("SELECT categoryName FROM category_table WHERE categoryNumber = :categoryNumber")
fun getCategoryName(categoryNumber: Int): String
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I cannot access room db on the main thread